# Radius AAA authentication failover

Tags: authentication, radius, aaa

I know this question has been asked on here but I cannot seem to figure this out.  I am trying to get radius to failover to local authentication but whenever I turn off radius it won't failover.  Below is my configuration:

```
aaa new-model

aaa authentication login WindowsAD group radius local

aaa authorization exec WindowsAD group radius local

enable password 7 05080F1C22431F5B4A

line vty 0 4

 password 7 0822455D0A16514244

 login authentication WindowsAD

 transport preferred telnet

 transport input telnet

line vty 5 15

 password 7 0822455D0A16514244

 login authentication WindowsAD

 transport preferred telnet
```

!
I would appreciate some help if you could.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you configure radius-server deadtime? I assume its a Aiornet AP?

Comment: I actually didn't.  I'm pretty new to networking.

Comment: This command is required configuration when multiple RADIUS servers are defined. If not configured, client authentication does not occur.
Follow link Configuring Settings for All RADIUS Servers

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/wireless/access_point/12.4_10b_JA/configuration/guide/scg12410b-chap13-radius-tacacs.html

Comment: O I am sorry! I thought you wanted to have a failover radius server, not local auth. That is a different story. Consider just doing 2 Radius servers insisted in group failover.

Comment: I just want it to failover to local for now.  Then I will build from there.